# How to know the classname of a WPF application to use in FindWindowByClassName InnoSetup function

Tags: wpf, inno-setup, classname, spy++

In InnoSetup, there is a function "FindWindowByClassName" to know if a program is allready in use.
In my case, I want to know if my wpf application is in use before runing the InnoSetup update, but I don't know how to know my wpf application class name. When I use Spy++ with my application, the class name is:

```
HwndWrapper[MuProgram.exe;;1120a18a-2e29-4e19-8653-939c99b505c2]
```

As you can see, there is a GUID in my class name, and this GUID changes at every launch.
But in any case, when I run InnoSetup (in debug mode), the FindWindowByClassName function returns 0 when I use this class name.

```
FindWindowByClassName('HwndWrapper[MyProgram.exe;;1120a18a-2e29-4e19-8653-939c99b505c2]'); // returns 0
```

I've tried to use only "MyProgram.exe" but the function allways returns 0 (the application "MyProgram.exe" is launched during the tests).
Have you any idea to fixe this problem? May I set the class name in my wpf code?

Comment: You can get your application window's class name [`this way`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8398853/960757), but it's not much reliable way to detect whether your application is running. Rather create a mutex in your application and check for it in InnoSetup by using the [`CheckForMutexes`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions) function.

Comment: It works great using a mutex. Thank a lot !

Comment: @TLama you should write that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the [Inno Script source code](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/4c3f93dc55b4d6a133af0c86f0981edd809a13ee/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L1446), you can see that FindWindowByClassName calls the Windows [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) function.  As you already noticed, the WPF form changes the class name on each invocation.  According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262375/550712), the random GUID makes it impossible to use FindWindow on WPF classes.

Unfortunately there is no RegEx or wildcard capability when searching for windows.  I guess you could write your own by searching through *all* windows using something like [GetWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) and looping through all children of the desktop window. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453697/550712) suggests using UI Automation rather than old API calls with WPF.

The mutex alternative suggested by @TLama is great if you're writing the app that you will search for. If you're trying to find and close another vendor's app, it's not so easy.  Also [CheckForMutexes](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_checkformutexes.htm) does not return a window handle, so it's not straightforward how to close the window.